# BLAZOR: Authorise detail page (https://blazorapp/Details/1)

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, blazor, blazor-client-side

In Razor / Blazor it is possible to authorise specific controllers or actions/pages in a controllor, but is it possible to add some more logic to the authorise logic?

simple:

You can only see this if you're an admin or superuser.

is 'normal' but i want to prevent that details only can be seen bij the owner of involved person.

For instance 
if (order.owner.id <> currentuser.id)
 No Acces 
else 
  showdetails

Comment: Are looking for this: [AuthorizeView component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component) ? It can be configured to work policy-based or role-based. In your case, I guess it would need to be [policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1). So the problem shifts to finding out how to setup a policy that will fit the requirement.

Comment: You can also use the `Authorize` attribute with [policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or [role-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) authorization.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing specific enough (part of the question is lost somehow)
But i want a more specific authorisation, i want to prevent that someone who is not the owner of the order can not see order #1. but that same person, as owner of order #2 can see that order #2 in detail.